# Cannot instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter" when run Spring Boot application on Tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I am a newbie on Spring Boot. Just built a Spring Boot example following the Spring Boot Tutorial on the official website, then deployed on the Tomcat with WAR format, got the errors as below when it starts to run:

```
2017-03-01 09:26:17.838  INFO 12568 --- [ost-startStop-1] hello.SpringBootWebApplicationTest       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-03-01 09:26:18.116  INFO 12568 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3c164927: startup date [Wed Mar 01 09:26:18 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-01 09:26:19.015  WARN 12568 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [hello.SpringBootWebApplicationTest]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter
2017-03-01 09:26:19.044 ERROR 12568 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [hello.SpringBootWebApplicationTest]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:461) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:138) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationImportFilters(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:279) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.filter(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:250) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:101) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:453) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader can not access a member of class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:135) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted

2017-03-01 09:26:19.050 ERROR 12568 --- [ina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springrestdemo]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springrestdemo]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [hello.SpringBootWebApplicationTest]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:461) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:138) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationImportFilters(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:279) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.filter(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:250) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:101) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:453) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader can not access a member of class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:135) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted

2017-03-01 09:26:19.053 ERROR 12568 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351) [bootstrap.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485) [bootstrap.jar:8.0.39]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2017-03-01 09:26:19.056 ERROR 12568 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina     : The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351) [bootstrap.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485) [bootstrap.jar:8.0.39]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

The  associated pom.xml content is like this:

```
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <artifactId>springrestdemo</artifactId>

  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springrestdemo Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.version>6.2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
        <springfox-swagger2.version>2.6.1</springfox-swagger2.version>
        <org.apache.directory.api.api-all.version>1.0.0-M28</org.apache.directory.api.api-all.version>
        <spring.framework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.5.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
         <start-class>hello.SpringBootWebApplicationTest</start-class>
    </properties>  

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>  

  <dependencies>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
           <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>  





    <!-- Swagger box for automatically generating doc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>    

    <!-- Swagger UI for Testing REST api -->    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>






     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.36</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>   


  </dependencies>


    <build>
    <finalName>springrestdemo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                  <fork>true</fork>
                  <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>        
            </plugin>

           <plugin>  
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
            <configuration>  
             <source>1.8</source>  
             <target>1.8</target>  
            </configuration>  
           </plugin>  
          </plugins>   
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Anyone can help? Thanks for your help in advance.

PS:
the code files lists are：

```
Greeting.java
GreetingController.java
SpringBootWebApplicationTest.java
under the same folder named "hello"
```

The configurations code is as below:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplicationTest extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplicationTest.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello World! in main");
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplicationTest.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please also post your configuration class

Comment: @artemisian, Have updated the configuration code into the post.Thanks~

Comment: Thanks, this is great info, give me sometime and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Check my answer, it should work.

Comment: @artemisian, awesome,that's the reason. It works. The issue cost me so much time.Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it worked. But most important you learn something new!

Comment: @artemisian, right!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Ron, in you pom file you are overriding spring dependency versions that are incompatible with the spring-boot version you are using, you need to let spring-boot to import is predefined spring dependency versions. Below is the relevant portion of the pom that needs to be changed:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.version>6.2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
    <springfox-swagger2.version>2.6.1</springfox-swagger2.version>
    <org.apache.directory.api.api-all.version>1.0.0-M28</org.apache.directory.api.api-all.version>
<!-- REMOVE THIS <spring.framework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.framework.version> -->
    <spring.boot.version>1.5.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<!-- REMOVE THIS <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version> -->
     <start-class>hello.SpringBootWebApplicationTest</start-class>
</properties>
```

Comment: On a similar error in gradle with Spring - removing version helped. Set dependency without specifiing version - let the framework choose the right one for you.